# Flexbox layout: how to set every item same width in multi rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Here is my [test demo](https://codepen.io/dyh333/pen/QoqoxL) in codepen. I hope to keep the same margin between items, so I use `flex-grow: 1` to fill the over width.

However, the items of last row seems not keep the same width as previous rows. How to do it?

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
 }
.col{
  min-width: 160px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background:#eee;
  height: 120px;
}
```

This is what I want, addon use flex-grow to keep the same margin
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `calc` to set the *width* or *flex-basis* property to `calc(33.33% - 30px)` so that it adjusts for the *right and left margins* you have applied to the `col` - see demo below:

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
}
.col{
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 30px);
  margin: 10px 15px;
  background:#eee;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but now the every row is limit to only 3 columns, is posible dynamic set by min-width=160px

Comment: but if you have `min-width` in smaller screens it will break this layout...

Answer (score 1):

I hope following code may solve your problem.

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
}
.col{
  flex: 1;
  min-width: calc(33.33% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 30px);
  margin: 10px 15px;
  background:#eee;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but now the every row is limit to only 3 columns, is posible dynamic set by min-width=160px

Answer (score 0):

your `min-width` can pull div to next row and i decrease it.

and you must use `flex` on columns and `flex-direction` on row

something like this:

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
.col{
  min-width: 20px;
 flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px 10px;
background:#eee;
 height: 120px;
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
a
</div>
<div class="col">
b
</div>
<div class="col">
c
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
.col{
  min-width: 200px;
 flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px 10px;
background:#eee;
 height: 120px;
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
a
</div>
<div class="col">
b
</div>
<div class="col">
c
</div>
<div class="col">
b
</div>
<div class="col">
c
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
.col{
  width: 200px;
 
  margin: 10px 10px;
background:#eee;
 height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
a
</div>
<div class="col">
b
</div>
<div class="col">
c
</div>
<div class="col">
b
</div>
<div class="col">
c
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the items is much that can not put in one row... I had update details in question

Comment: it's automatically will go to next row but if you want to be in one row you must remove min-width.

Comment: the min-width is need, and auto goto next row is ok. but i hope items keep same width

Comment: ok see all results. and you can use max-width too